# How to extract json strings from unstructured log file?

Tags: java, json, regex, logging

I got logs like this, in which some information is output as json.

```
2016-03-21 21:36:20.878  INFO 17512 --- [main] This is going well.
ok: [goingwell] => {
    "localresult": {
        "aa":"bb",
        "aaa":"bbb"
    }
}
2016-03-21 21:36:31.172  INFO 17513 --- [main] Continue logging ...
2016-03-21 21:36:42.568  INFO 17514 --- [main] With more json strings...
ok: [xxa123] => {
    "axaxaxa": {
        "aada":"bb",
        "aaadfa":"bbb"
    }
}
2016-03-21 21:36:43.132  INFO 17515 --- [main] Continue logging ...
2016-03-21 21:36:45.428  INFO 17516 --- [main] With more json strings...
ok: [xxa123] => {
  "ccc": {
    "ddd": {
      "eee": {
        "fff": "ggg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to get each json string with Java?

This json might be nested.

I know using PCRE can do this with recursive matching(`\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}` ), but Java seems have no good library to support PCRE.

Is there a good way to achieve this using java code/library?

(I had an ugly solution, by restraining the recursive depth of above regex.)

Comment: You can analyze the log and see if there is a flow when the JSON comes. For e.g. if you are sure that "This is going well." is always followed by JSON, you can write an if case and then call the JSON fetching code of yours.

Comment: @Limit Thanks, but it's not the case. [goingwell] might be any text.

Comment: Just curious if you found a good solution?

Comment: @wwkudu Sorry for late reply

Comment: @wwkudu Sorry for late reply. The solution is only to transform `\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}` to non-PCRE... With limited recursive depth.